# Why is mercurial's hg rebase so slow?

Tags: git, performance, version-control, mercurial, rebase

The `rebase` extension to mercurial provides functionality similar to git's `rebase`.

Letting the rebase execute takes something like 4 minutes (~240 s) for 100 commits.

In my imagination this should be extremely fast, a few seconds at most, but clearly I'm missing something.

What makes it take so long? Are the commits themselves just extremely expensive?

Comment: I suppose you'd have to construct identical test cases in hg and git to can an objective comparison. But IMHO with hg I do agree that rebasing is not fast.

Comment: I've regularly rebased my changes of this size frequently and I faced similar slowdowns where there are blobs in the commits. Do you have blobs in your source branch/head that you are trying to rebase? Calculating the sha for blobs might be the killer here.

Comment: @Arun you mean like binary blobs? In the repo, there are probably somewhere. In the set of commits I'm rebasing, there are no binary blobs.

Answer (score 8):

By default, rebase writes to the working copy, but you can configure it to run in-memory for better performance, and to allow it to run if the working copy is dirty.
Just add following lines in your `.hgrc` file:

```
[rebase]

experimental.inmemory = True
```

(To get more configuration for rebase try to run `hg help rebase`)

Comment: But why is writing to the working copy even slow? It would seem that it's way to slow to even be bottle necked by disk io unless there's a massive amount of io that I'm not thinking about, no?

Comment: Interesting; I rebased about 70 changesets. I tried it both ways. This was initially MUCH faster - first 20 or so. Then it slowed down to seemingly normal. Still better overall.

Comment: I see what happened. It sped along in memory until it hit a conflict; then it started over on disk instead, and it redid ALL the ones that had it gotten through before the conflict.

Comment: I did another with 115 changesets - no conflicts - and it must have been ~5x faster.